# Why does Python recognize my imports and sometimes not?

Tags: python, init, modulenotfounderror

My imports are acting strangely depending where I run Python.

I have a project with the following structure:

```
repo-name
|_ .github
|_ actual_code
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ main.py
  |_ constants.py
|_ Dockerfile
|_ virtual_environment
|_ other stuff
```

Within `main.py`, I have the import statement:

```
from actual_code.constants import CONSTANT_A, CONSTANT_B
```

which works when I am running code in the console of the IDE (I use PyCharm, Community Edition), but if I try to run it in the PowerShell console via `python actual_code/main.py` it gives me the ModuleNotFoundError (as if `__init__.py` were missing);

if I change my import statement to

```
from constants import CONSTANT_A, CONSTANT_B
```

then it stops working in the console of the IDE, but it works without any issues in the PowerShell console

I would like to know:
A) why this is happening and
B) what can I do about it? it feels stupid to change back and forth depending on where I run my code

I expected the same code to work the same way whether I run it in the IDE or in a PowerShell console, but I need to change the import depending on where I run it. The working directory is the same in both cases, namely "repo-name"

Comment: Don't run `python actual_code/main.py` -- that's treating `actual_code` like a regular filesystem directory, not like a Python module. Something like `python -m actual_code.main` would be less bad -- that way your main won't be invoked unless you're in an appropriate parent directory with an appropriate PYTHONPATH/`sys.path`/etc.

Comment: It depends on what the "current working directory" is.  `import xxx` does not look in the directory where the script is, it looks in the "current directory".  It is easy to add the script's home to `sys.path` to get around this.

Comment: Anyhow -- can you provide a [mre] with exact steps we can follow to cause the problem ourselves?

Comment: i agree with @TimRoberts. my first comment is the current working directory that the IDE uses.

Comment: Many thanks for the replies! @TimRoberts how do you add the script's home to `sys.path`? @Charles Duffy I've managed to run it as a package now (thanks for the good advice), but it still doesn't seem to solve the problem. As for a minimal reproducible example, that might be difficult because I am not sure what it would include (sorry, I'm very much of a beginner at programming...)

Comment: If you want to add the script's directory to the Python path, you just do `sys.path.append( os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))` before you attempt your local imports.

Comment: Many thanks @TimRoberts! I'll add this right away!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the filepath of the import may be resolved differently depending on what program is executing the python file. Running your program in PyCharm, the working directory is likely the root of your project. In PowerShell, this may not be the case as the working directory may be the current directory and not the root level project directory.

To fix this, you can use absolute imports and specify the full path of the module from the root directory. So something along the lines of this, where `repo_name` is the top-level package name of the project:

```
from repo_name.actual_code.constants import CONSTANT_A, CONSTANT_B
```

Comment: Well, he can use that **IF** the directory containing `repo_name` is in the Python path.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, and sorry for taking to long to get back! This is a good suggestion, but there is a hyphen in the project name (to align with the version on GitHub), so I'm not sure how that would work. Do you have an example? BTW: in both PyCharm and PowerShell the working directory is the same